# CodeIgniter use different 404 page on front-end and back-end

Tags: php, codeigniter, http-status-code-404

Hi I'd like to ask a question please. I'm building a project in which I'm having this folder structure:

```
application
- controllers
-- posts.php // this is on frontend
-- admin
--- posts.php // this is on backend obviously
```

So in both cases if I try to access from the url a post that doesn't exist I'll do something like this

```
$data['post'] = $this->post_model->get_by_id($id);
count($data['post']) || show_404(); // Return 404 if post not found
```

which shows the default 404 Codeigniter page.

Is it possible to set a different 404 page for front end and back end and if so how can I do this ?

The only options I have thought so far are these:

1. Have the same custom 404 page for both front end and back end, in which case I only have to set a different 404 view to the default file, but I don't think its the best option.

2 (not tested). Create 2 different controllers and views, like this

```
applicatiom
- controllers
-- front404.php
-- admin
--- admin404.php
```

so when I check if the post exist, it would become like this

```
 count($data['post']) || redirect('admin/admin404'); // on back-end
count($data['post']) || redirect('admin/front404'); // on front-end
```

3 (not test). A similar to 2nd option, but setting the `$route['404_override'] = '';` dynamically ??

However I was wondering if there's a more efficient way of doing this. Btw I'm using CodeIgniter v3.

Comment: Just a brain bubble: create `admin404.php` with content `require '../path_here/front404.php';`

Answer (score 0):

When you have

`application/controllers/Error404.php` and `application/controllers/admin/Error404.php`,

setting `$route['404_override']` to '`Error404`' will cause admin/Error404.php to be loaded if you visit /admin/non-existing-uri.

I do have to say this though - you shouldn't 404 based on whether items exist in a list or not. The list itself still exists, even if empty.

```
application/controllers/admin/Error404.php

application/controllers/Error404.php
```

Your Router settings should be as below

```
$route['404_override'] = 'Error404';
```

Thats it.